# Error when saving model for the second time in Django

Tags: django

I have following models structure:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
     fieldA = models.TextField()
     fieldB = models.TextField()

class Child(Parent):
     fieldC = models.CharField()
```

I noticed some unexpected behavior in following code snippet:

```
child = Child(fieldA = 'Text fieldA', fieldB = 'Text fieldB', fieldC = 'Text fieldC')
child.full_clean()
child.save()

self.assertEqual(Child.objects.count(), 1)
child.delete()
self.assertEqual(Child.objects.count(), 0)

child.full_clean()
child.save()
```

Not getting into why I add the second `child.save()`, assertions are passed, but when I want to save it with this second error it is failing with `ValueError`:

> ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved
>   related object 'parent_ptr'

At the same time I don't see any such error with following code:

```
parent = Parent(fieldA = 'Text fieldA', fieldB = 'Text fieldB')
parent.full_clean()
parent.save()

self.assertEqual(Parent.objects.count(), 1)
parent.delete()
self.assertEqual(Parent.objects.count(), 0)

parent.full_clean()
parent.save()
```

Why is that happening? Is someone able to tell me how I am supposed to fix the first snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that you're taking advantage of a feature called "multi-table inheritance".

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

What this means is that instead of `Child` representing a table with three fields, it only has two fields: `fieldC` and a foreign key (`OneToOneField`) to a record in `Parent`.

When you delete the `Child`, it deletes both the `Child` and `Parent` rows. When you try to save the instance of `Child` again, the value of the `parent_ptr` `OneToOneField` still contains the ID of the old `Parent` row, which points to something that doesn't exist anymore.

You probably want to use abstract base classes instead:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

```
class Base(models.Model):
     fieldA = models.TextField()
     fieldB = models.TextField()
     class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Parent(Base):
    pass

class Child(Base):
     fieldC = models.CharField()
```

Here, there is no link between `Parent` and `Child`: the table that `Child` represents has three fields, and the table that `Parent` represents has two fields.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification. Yes, abstract class would be great here, but since I need to have also objects of `Parent` type with their own table I cannot use it here.

Comment: @sebap123 In the example I listed, `Parent` and `Child` both have their own table. The abstract model doesn't get its own table; it's almost like a template for a table.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. I don't know how I missed that. Is there any difference (beside resolving my issue) with using this approach over the regular inheritance I am using? Is one option better than the other? Online I can only find info regarding table creation being the single difference.

Comment: @sebap123 Generally I'd recommend abstract models as the right answer always. Unless you have a specific need for model inheritance, stick with abstract models. It's very rarely the case that you want to share one table for multiple models; it's useful only for very specific use cases. If you had one of those use cases, you'd know it ;)